# jQuery - Select non-sibling element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Basically what I am trying to do is hide the spans initially and show the respective span when I click on an input field and when you leave that input field, that span goes away.

So I have a form that looks something like this (simplified):

```
<form id="form">
  <div id="contact-div-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FNAME" class="field validation" id="mce-FNAME">
  </div>
  <span>
    Please Enter Your First Name
  </span>
  <div id="contact-div-2">
    <input  type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LNAME" class="field validation" id="mce-LNAME">
  </div>
  <span>
    Please Enter Your Last Name
  </span>
  <div id="contact-div-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="EMAIL" class="field validation" id="mce-EMAIL">
  </div>
  <span>
    Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address
  </span>
</form>
```

This is currently the JavaScript code that I have but it is not working properly.

```
$("#form span").hide();
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).next('span').fadeIn("slow");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).next('span').fadeOut("slow");
}); //end blur
```

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. Takes about an hour, and would arm you with not just the answer to this question, but the dozen other similar questions you'll find yourself facing over time. Probably pays back that hour within a week.

Answer (score 2):

The `<span>` elements are siblings with the parent `<div>` elements of each `<input>`, so you need to use `$(this).parent()`:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('span').fadeIn("slow");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('span').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pupdvz3e/)

Also, to reduce repetition in your code, your "focus" and "blur" handlers can be combined, using `.bind()` with `.fadeToggle()`:

```
$("input").bind("focus blur", function() {
    $(this).parent().next("span").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey17m466/)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing next to the input, try

```
$(this).parent().next('span').fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
  <div id="contact-div-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FNAME" class="field validation" id="mce-FNAME">
      <span> Please Enter Your First Name </span>
  </div>
  <div id="contact-div-2">
    <input  type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LNAME" class="field validation" id="mce-LNAME">
  <span> Please Enter Your Last Name </span>
  </div>
  <div id="contact-div-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="EMAIL" class="field validation" id="mce-EMAIL">
  <span> Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**js**

```
$("#form span").hide();

$("input").on('focus', function(){
   var s = $(this).siblings('span');
    s.fadeIn("slow");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).next('span').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Fiddle: [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p17eynhc/)

Answer (score 0):

Since your span is sibling of the parent div, instead of the input, you must navigate to the div

```
$("#form span").hide();
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('span').fadeIn("slow");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('span').fadeOut("slow");
}); //end blur
```

If you have control over the HTML, and both the span and input hold related information, it may also make sense to put them close together (i.e., child of the same div). Your original js code would work, then.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
  <div id="contact-div-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FNAME" class="field validation" id="mce-FNAME">
        <span>
    Please Enter Your First Name
  </span>
  </div>

  <div id="contact-div-2">
    <input  type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="LNAME" class="field validation" id="mce-LNAME">
        <span>
    Please Enter Your Last Name
  </span>
  </div>

  <div id="contact-div-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="EMAIL" class="field validation" id="mce-EMAIL">
        <span>
    Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address
  </span>
  </div>

</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#form span").hide();
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).next('span').fadeIn("slow");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).next('span').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/k2ko9gu8/)

Answer (score -1):

You can give id's to your spans that are a function of say the name attribute of the corresponding input and then refer to them directly that way... this way you are also not as captive to whether or not you change the design where the hierarchy isn't the same  etc.

For example:

```
<span id="span_FNAME">...</span>
```

Then jquery

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    var s = '#span_'+$(this).attr("name");
    $(s).fadeIn("slow")
...
```